# How do you integrate Google Analytics and Tags with Next.js 13's app router setup?

Tags: typescript, next.js

Next.js has documentation that covers Google Analytics and Tag Manager, but it's identical between the app router and pages router documentation, so I wonder if it was just not updated yet. Can anyone explain how to integrate these properly within a Next.js 13 installation that uses app router? Every example I see online uses the pages router setup, and isn't applicable to my installation. Really appreciate the help!!